# Script to Backup Data to Remote Location. The data to backup depends on the day of the week

Tags: shell, powershell

I have a script that I wrote, and I'm sure that there is a better way to do it, but can't for the life of me figure it out.

Here is the problem statement:
I need to backup data to a remote location, but what actually gets backed up depends on what day of the week it is. I have a program that creates a folder with the date of business as the name (yyyymmdd). Usually this happens late at night, either at 11:55 pm or later. Which means when this scripts runs, it could possibly be the next day, though we are looking for a folder with the previous day's date. Finally, if the dated folder is for a Sunday, we need to back up the previous 3 days of data, i.e. Friday, Saturday, and Sunday.

I am using mostly `if` statements, but there has to be a better way to this.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Code:

```
    # Get today's date
    $currdate = [datetime]::Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    # If the current day is a Monday or (i.e. last DOB is Sunday),
    # that means that we have to grab the last 3 days (Friday, Saturday, and Sunday) of data
    $currdayofweek = [datetime]::Today.DayOfWeek

    if ( ($currdayofweek -ne 'Sunday') -or ($currdayofweek -ne 'Monday')) {
        # It is not Sunday or Monday, we do not have to backup the last 3 days,
        # only the current or previous day's data
        if ( !(Test-Path -Path "$iber\$currdate" -PathType Container )) {
 # A dated sub folder for the current day does not exist
 # It is after midnight and we need to use the previous day's
 # date of business
 $currdate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
 # Copy the dated sub folder, archive and settlement
 copyItems -sourceInput "$iber\$currdate" -destinationInput "$uncroot\$backup\"
 Copy-Item -Path "$iber\ARCHIVE\$currdate.zip" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
 Copy-Item -Path "$iber\EDC" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\EDC" -Filter "$currdate.stl" -Recurse
 RunGenPoll -inputfolder "$iber\$currdate"
        } else {
           # A dated sub folder the current day does exist
            # It is before midnight and we can use the current day's
            # date of business

            # Copy the dated sub folder, archive and settlement
            copyItems -sourceInput "$iber\$currdate" -destinationInput "$uncroot\$backup\"
            Copy-Item -Path "$iber\ARCHIVE\$currdate.zip" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
            Copy-Item -Path "$iber\EDC" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\EDC" -Filter "$currdate.stl" -Recurse
  RunGenPoll -inputfolder "$iber\$currdate"
        }
    } elseif ($currdayofweek -eq 'Monday') {
            # Day of the week is Monday
            # We need to see if it is Monday morning (dob Sunday), or 
            # Monday evening (dob Monday)
            if ( !(Test-Path -Path "$iber\$currdate" -PathType Container) ) {
                # It is Monday and after midnight on Sunday
                # Copy Friday, Saturday and Sunday's data
                $currdate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

                LogInfo -LogLine "Copying Archive files to $uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
   $archivesubs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$iber\ARCHIVE" | Where-Object { $_ -like "20*" } | Sort-Object -Descending
   $archivesubs | Select-Object -Index (1..$archivenum) | Copy-Item -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE" -Recurse -Force

                LogInfo -LogLine "Copying dated sub folders to $uncroot\$backup"
   $datedsubs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$iber"| Where-Object { $_ -like "20*" } | Sort-Object -Descending
   $datedsubs | Select-Object -Index (1..$datednum) | Copy-Item -Destination "$uncroot\$backup" -Recurse

                LogInfo -LogLine "Copying EDC files"
                Robocopy.exe "$env:EDCPATH" "$uncroot\$backup\EDC" *.* /XF $edcexclude
   # Copy the dated sub folder, archive and settlement
   RunGenPoll -inputfolder "$iber\$currdate"
        } else {
                # It is Monday and we have a dated sub folder for Monday 
                # Copy the dated sub folder, archive and settlement

                copyItems -sourceInput "$iber\$currdate" -destinationInput "$uncroot\$backup\"
                LogInfo -LogLine "Copying Archive files to $uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
   Copy-Item -Path "$iber\ARCHIVE\$currdate.zip" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
   LogInfo -LogLine "Copying EDC files"
   Copy-Item -Path "$iber\EDC" -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\EDC" -Filter "$currdate.stl" -Recurse
                RunGenPoll -inputfolder "$iber\$currdate"
  }
} else {
  # It is Sunday
  # Copy data for Friday, Saturday and Sunday
  LogInfo -LogLine "Copying Archive files to $uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE"
  $archivesubs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$iber\ARCHIVE" | Where-Object { $_ -like "20*" } | Sort-Object -Descending
  $archivesubs | Select-Object -Index (1..$archivenum) | Copy-Item -Destination "$uncroot\$backup\ARCHIVE" -Recurse -Force

            LogInfo -LogLine "Copying dated sub folders to $uncroot\$backup"
  $datedsubs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$iber"| Where-Object { $_ -like "20*" } | Sort-Object -Descending
  $datedsubs | Select-Object -Index (1..$datednum) | Copy-Item -Destination "$uncroot\$backup" -Recurse

            LogInfo -LogLine "Copying EDC files"
            Robocopy.exe "$env:EDCPATH" "$uncroot\$backup\EDC" *.* /XF $edcexclude
  RunGenPoll -inputfolder "$iber\$currdate"
    }
```

Please let me know if anyone needs any clarification on anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about checking the current time instead of checking the existence of the subfolder.

The script below has a function to back up the data of the specified date.

```
function Backup-Data ([string]$Path, [string]$Dest, [datetime]$Date) {

    $baseName = $Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Copy-Item "$Path\$baseName" $Dest -Recurse
    Copy-Item "$Path\ARCHIVE\$baseName.zip" "$Dest\ARCHIVE"
    Copy-Item "$Path\EDC\$baseName.stl" "$Dest\EDC"
    RunGenPoll -InputFolder "$Path\$baseName"
}


$backupPath = "$uncroot\$backup"
$now = Get-Date
$targetDate = if ($now.Hour -lt 12) { $now.AddDays(-1).Date } else { $now.Date }

if ($targetDate.DayOfWeek -eq "Sunday") {
    -2..0 | ForEach-Object { Backup-Data $iber $backupPath $targetDate.AddDays($_) }
}
else {
    Backup-Data $iber $backupPath $targetDate
}
```

If you run the script in the morning,  the `$targetDate` will be previous day.
If `$targetDate.DayofWeek` is Sunday, it will backup data from two days ago to today.